# Error building dockerfile "E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found."

Tags: apt, docker

I am building a dockerfile. It starts with:

```
RUN apt-get -yqq update && apt-get install -yqq iptables ca-certificates lxc openjdk-6-jdk git-core lxc-docker
```

when I build the dockerfile this error occurs:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
```

I don't know how to deal with this and will be grateful for some help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same error while tweaking an old Ubuntu 16.04-based image. The solution was to do this first in the dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
```

This package allows `apt` to use `https` sources.